# Why ret disappear with optimization?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, compiler-optimization, inline-assembly

```
int suma(int* array, int len)
{
    asm("    xor %eax, %eax           # resultado = 0   \n"
        "    xor %edx, %edx           # i = 0           \n"
        "1:  add (%rdi,%rdx,4), %eax  # res += array[i] \n"
        "    inc %edx                 # ++i             \n"
        "    cmp %edx,%esi            # i < len?        \n"
        "    jne 1b                   # repetir         \n"
//      "    ret                                        \n"
       );
}

int main()
{
    int v[100];
    return suma(v, 100);
}
```

Why is it that gcc inserts `ret` at the end of `suma()` on `-O0`, but I have to add it myself on `-O3`?

From `gcc -v`:

```
gcc version 8.2.1 20181011 (Red Hat 8.2.1-4) (GCC)
```

Comment: Maybe it is inlined into `main` which already has a ret instruction. Without seeing the complete result it is hard to guess.

Comment: I'm not sure, but note that technically speaking, your entire inline assembly is not really well-defined because you assume that certain registers hold certain values which is not a valid assumption to make.

Comment: I assume 64bit..., array in rdi, len in esi.

Comment: Look at [this](https://www.godbolt.org/z/i_hcN2). It is inlined but nevertheless the code for the `suma` function is generated as well, and there the `ret` has not been removed.
How did you notice that there is no `ret` with -O3?

Comment: dissasemble with objdump

Comment: It's a tail recursion optimisation. `suma` can just return to where `main` returns. Haskell compilers are even *required* to implement it (since there is no iteration).

Comment: make your asm volatile and the optimizer won't help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I assume 64bit..., array in rdi, len in esi.

You're using *inline* asm, and not in a `__attribute__((naked,noinline))` function, so the compiler can use the inline asm template block in any context it wants.  Since you failed to use any input/output constraints, and you clobber registers without telling the compiler, it will just totally break unless you disable optimization.

To answer the main question, the compiler simply inlines `suma` into `main`.  It's implicitly `volatile` (because it's a basic asm statement) so it isn't optimized away.

**But execution falls off the end of a non-void function (`suma`), which is undefined behaviour**, so modern GCC just gives up and omits the `ret` instruction.  It assumes that execution can never take that path (because of the undefined behaviour), and doesn't bother generating code for it.

If you add a `return 0;` to the end of `suma`, then `main` will end with a `ret` instruction.

Surprisingly, [gcc only gives one warning on the Godbolt compiler explorer with -O3 -Wall](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5HhYEA1IJEBbJhFkEAVPKbFiTAJ6l5G%2BQ0wsAlBwAMAQQ4B2Pvfludg5RG5d38gB4k8twArJhM/sah4f5%2BcW7cAMzyxJhKDARM6KjBiQAi8jbuHCEAwiw%2BtnbxCVy%2B7oHEwVxh6JHNrbE1xVzJeLkFRd0JZRV1Vd0%2BtCBuWejy3i3E%2BKShy5EALJZRLTG1yamCzXz5OnqGJTx4JQUl5ZWuNT5%2BssgdmG3Dk73H/P1fI3u40e8We7mQygADu82qtdoJ/l8kiZcqUzBYOIkAGKTUYPapPOp%2BKgsTDyWgAIwB3wOmEhmAIeCauKBXCqAHp2aCie5UgpqQLBXcxmyQX5rIkXA57JyufE%2BWIWIVMVKnHkqlVTKpZBBrPYnFKXnJ5AA3S60Gw2G4qia8hmKxQqNQm4wWmwS1WOPJSbYMaQhKSkFjSGyB1DSUr8fiKUTiMlJWiBgghn3bADWIESiQAdFm8/mCwA2RjSDaB4NSUOkcNSQOCEA2UjJys%2B0hwWAwRAoVBQvDmMgUCBoXv9kDAAAcXFIADM%2BwRMMR6xAKSnSBTZLoDNJE6Rh8oLAQAPIsBhblukLCqNjmVf4VLIRkmtKrzD%2BTDIETz7eBjSYP1SHcCGIPBlG/X1WHYKNeEYPAKXrSBtlQSFGVQFh6ykABaQ9kgwgB1JgGAYeQMNUcQEExPIECYQQAHc/wYOtYwkOhfX9ctVxrfxx0LDDCw2eRgGQN5x2zXwIFwQgggTYxSh7SE%2BwXZpEloSx5EjXh%2BCTFNLHTTMcwLAy82Lf8y1IUDCy4bMAE4gw46Q6wbJttLbTsICQUQCEhT9yEoYd5NHegPkk4g6FIGj9EhMCSykANbPPGsE3kGjCAQAJuN4/jBOE0StJbHTSAQcIsBC3VotM0DEkcbN6ArKsawcxtm1DfKMyzXNDIM4zpESdj4vspy8pc%2BA3O7EcFx8oc5IUkLkGYNhHEtGc5wXJcV3PdcWE3b9dx7fc5GPU9b0wK9gBvc873fR9n3PV930/SQAJ/OQ/22oCQKiubII06CGFg%2BDSqQlC0OkLCcPwwjiNI5ByPyKjaPoxixGYlToti2qw2kLieL4%2BRZog%2BQqpsbMinE/AiCaaS1Km/slK4VT1L4Xhcua3S2o6gyyt6ur%2BvrRrtNYqQuC5jHawGlnSCfRc8FQkANiAA%3D):

```
<source>: In function 'int suma(int*, int)':
<source>:13:1: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
```

The resulting asm output for `main` is this, which is of course totally broken because RDI is `argc`; it never reserved space for `int v[100]` because its unused in the C source or did anything.

```
main:
            xor %eax, %eax           # resultado = 0   
    xor %edx, %edx           # i = 0           
1:  add (%rdi,%rdx,4), %eax  # res += array[i] 
    inc %edx                 # ++i             
    cmp %edx,%esi            # i < len?        
    jne 1b                   # repetir
```

With a `return 0;` at the end of `suma`, it and main end with `xorl    %eax, %eax` ; `ret`, but of course `main` is still totally broken because the inline asm doesn't use any input constraints.